# Publishing will be delayed Broad host permissions error Chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

We're trying to work out how to resolve this issue, the current issue we have is our extension works on a unlimited amount of websites 1 of the features is a time & screenshot monitor so employer can track freelancers work other feature is ability to highlight text on any site and run a amazon search for the highlighted text for example.

We are always updating and any issues got fixed within 24-48 hours now with this happening every time we have to wait 1-3 weeks for a review according to google devs.

If we change the manifest to specific websites only then 99% of the time our extensions not going to work on all the other sites not listed. Can we do something else?

IF ANYONE HAS A SOLUTION OF WHAT WE CAN CHANGE TO MAKE THIS WORK I'M ALL EARS!

Comment: The only workaround is to use ["optional_permissions"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) instead of "permissions" and [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API with RequestContentScript (it's actually supported in Stable despite the warningin documentation) or [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#programmatic) instead of "content_scripts".

Comment: Would you be willing to speak to my dev? Can we contact you somehow ? If you allow.

Comment: No, use the linked info.

Comment: Thanks Anyway. Need someone who can do some paid work with us to get it solved. I'm not the tech guy. Appreciate it though